# Extend enumerations types in F#

Tags: f#, extension-methods

Another question related to F# feature called ["Type extensions"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211.aspx).

It seems impossible to extend enumerations in F#. I use [C# Extensions Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) a lot for extending enums: add range validation logic, method that returns string representation etc.

Unfortunately it seems possible extend only discriminated union but **impossible to extend simple enumerations**:

**1. Intrinsic extension**

```
// CustomEnum.fs
module CustomEnumModule

type CustomEnum = 
    | Value1 = 1
    | Value2 = 2

// Trying to split definition of the enum
type CustomEnum with 
    | Value3 = 3
```

**Error: "error FS0010: Unexpected symbol '|' in member definition"**

**2. Optional extension**

```
// CustomEnumEx.fs
open CustomEnumModule

type CustomEnum with
    member public x.PrintValue() =
        printfn "%A" x
```

**Error: "error FS0896: Enumerations cannot have members"**

It seems weird for me because (1) we can treat simple enumerations as a special case of full-featured discriminated union and we **can** extend discriminated unions and (2) extending .NET enums is a good way to add some features (including FP-features) to existing infrastructure.

Is this behavior intentional or this is simple bug in implementation?

P.S. Unfortunately [F# Spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html) is silent in this regard, or at least I can't find any proofs for one or another behavior there.

Comment: There was a similar question on Hubfs (aka FPish) a while back: [Extension method on Enum not allowed?](http://cs.hubfs.net/topic/None/59784) which suggests that it is not possible and is by design

Comment: Thanks for the link. And I agree that this **could be by design**. I can't understand what the rationale behind this decision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to create a module with the same name as a type which is similar to extending the type:

```
type CustomEnum = Value1 = 1 | Value2 = 2

[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module CustomEnum =
    let Print = function
    | CustomEnum.Value1 -> "One"
    | CustomEnum.Value2 -> "Two"
    | _ -> invalidArg "" ""

let value = CustomEnum.Value1

let s = CustomEnum.Print value
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution. I'm still wondering, why F# dev team decided to not implement this feature for enums.

Comment: I'd recommend giving feedback on the issue to the F# team via fsbugs-at-microsoft.com and [User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/30935-languages-f-), they have responded to and fixed many of the issues I have reported.

Comment: Thansks, I'll definitely do this!